# Combine two result sets in we API response

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi

I am using `.Net core 3.1` and looking for a way to combine two result sets-

I have a result set which returns following fields-

```
{
  "studentId": 1001,
  "studentName": "John Smot",
  "studentGrade": 5
},
{
  "studentId": 1002,
  "studentName": "Amy Johnson",
  "studentGrade": 4
}
```

I have one more result set which returns student category info-

```
{
  "categoryId": 1000,
  "categoryName": "EVS",
  "studentId": 1001
},
{
  "categoryId": 1000,
  "categoryName": "EVS",
  "studentId": 1002
}
```

In short, category result set returns student Id as well which comes under it. So here both students belongs to category 1000.

I want to combine 1st result with 2nd so that it will return category along with student information-

```
 {
      "studentId": 1001,
      "studentName": "John Smot",
      "studentGrade": 5,
      "categoryId": 1000
    },
    {
      "studentId": 1002,
      "studentName": "Amy Johnson",
      "studentGrade": 4,
      "categoryId": 1000
    }
```

Both results are coming from different sources, I am not sure if there is direct way to do this. Can someone please suggest what would be the quickest way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself? Stack Overflow does not exist to write your code for you.

Comment: @IanKemp Not attempted but investigated and did not find exact solution. Anyway I was looking for a way to do this.. not the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code and description, it seems that the result set is a json string, right? If that is the case, after getting the result set, first, you could base on the result to create models, and use the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize()` method to convert the JSON string to Object, then, you could get the result using LINQ query statement.

Refer the following sample:

Models:

```
public class StudentInfo
{
    public int studentId { get; set; }
    public string stuendtName { get; set; }
    public int studentGrade { get; set; }
}
public class CategoryInfo
{
    public int categoryId { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public int studentId { get; set; }
}
public class StudentCategoryViewModel
{
    public int studentId { get; set; }
    public string stuendtName { get; set; }
    public int studentGrade { get; set; }
    public int categoryId { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
        //required using System.Text.Json;
        var studentjsonstr = "[{\"studentId\":1001,\"stuendtName\":\"John Smot\",\"studentGrade\":5},{\"studentId\":1002,\"stuendtName\":\"Amy Johnson\",\"studentGrade\":4}]";
        var categoryjsonstr = "[{\"categoryId\":1000,\"categoryName\":\"EVS\",\"studentId\":1001},{\"categoryId\":1000,\"categoryName\":\"EVS\",\"studentId\":1002}]";
        var studentlist = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<StudentInfo>>(studentjsonstr);
        var categorylist = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CategoryInfo>>(categoryjsonstr);
        
        var result = studentlist.Select(c => new StudentCategoryViewModel()
        {
            studentId = c.studentId,
            stuendtName = c.stuendtName,
            studentGrade = c.studentGrade,
            categoryId = categorylist.Where(d => d.studentId == c.studentId).FirstOrDefault().categoryId
        }).ToList();
```

The screenshot like this, and then, you could return the result to the client.

[image]

Reference: [How to serialize and deserialize JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1)